# How to store windows directory links in MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am developing an e-Commerce website for my academic project and I need to show products in my home page. I need to show all my products from the database. For my images of products I thought one simple way. I will store the paths for every image in the table of products in my database under, a column `product_image`.

```
Product_Id   Product_Name   Product_Description        Product_Image              Product_Price  Product_Stock
1            HeadFirstJava  Java Programming Language  c:\products\headfirst.jpg  330            30
```

But when I am retrieving all the products information from database in my JSP page, I am not getting any images. I checked database the image paths are stored without backslashes.

What is the problem? How do I store those paths?

Comment: You might want to consult the documentation of google about the basic facts of 'escaping' those backslashes.

Comment: Show the code you are using to insert the data into the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to insert values with backslash using `PHP`, `C#` and any other, be sure to *escape* it another backlash.

if you try to insert this value, surely it will fail:

```
$value = "C:\Windows\Addins";
```

but this one is fine:

```
$value = "C:\\Windows\\Addins";
```

Answer (score 0):

'\' is used for escaping special characters, how do you do the insertions?
Try using `'\\'` like `c:\\products\\headfirst.jpg`

Comment: Thanks to all i got the answer in windows "\" will be escape character when we are storing in MySQL. So we need to use "\\".